# Multi-line Fields in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2016

I am working on a report in Crystal Reports 2016. The table used by the report, USER_ADDR, stores the addresses in its ADDRESS column, storing  additional information about the address (ex: apartment #) in a second line.

USER_ADDR Table

| ACCOUNT_ID | ADDRESS_LINE | ADDRESS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1234 Orange Ln |
| 2 | 1 | 1259 Apple Dr |
| 2 | 2 | APT 209 |
| 3 | 1 | 4962 Kiwi Pl |

I am using the field USER_ADDR.ADDRESS to show the address, but it only shows the first address line, which does not show the complete address if an account has an ADDRESS_LINE of 2.

1. How would I go about making a formula in Crystal Reports to show all lines of the ADDRESS column when an ACCOUNT_ID has an address where ADDRESS_LINE = 1 and 2.

or

2. How would I make a formula that only includes an ACCOUNT_ID's address where ADDRESS_LINE = 2

For reference, the report I'm modifying has the below columns:

| Account | Address Line 1 | Address Line 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |

Thank you!

*What I've tried: opened the Format Editor and selected the "Can Grow" option, hoping that would allow ADDR.ADDRESS to be multi-line but that did not work.*

Answer (score 0):

Use a detail-level formula to declare a global string variable and append the information using Chr(10) + Chr(13) to inject new lines.
Reset the variable in the group header.
Display the result in the Group footer.
Suppress the detail section.